# How do I not destroy an UDP port when binding a socket?

Tags: c, macos, sockets, networking, udp

I am using [GCDAsyncUdpSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/blob/master/GCD/GCDAsyncUdpSocket.h) to open an UDP socket and then I bind it to a port. The class is just a wrapper around the usual POSIX socket calls like `socket`, `bind`, etc.

**SCENARIO 1:**

- MyMacBook: start process A
- MyMacBook: open UDP port 23141 => SUCCESS
- SomeComputer: send an UDP packet to MyMacBook, port 23141
- MyMacBook: the standard OSX firewall asks me if i want to allow incoming network connections, and I agree.
- MyMacBook: ignore packet, don't read it. (or at least, i don't see a log message that tells me that i got a packet. either my code is broken, or the CocoaAsyncSocket code is broken, or the OS didn't report the packet to my program.)
- MyMacBook: kill process A
- MyMacBook: start process A
- MyMacBook: open UDP port 23141 => FAIL: `Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=48 "Address already in use" UserInfo=0x100407f30 {NSLocalizedDescription=Address already in use, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Error in bind() function`

Why???

```
netstat -n |grep 2314
udp4     626      0  *.23146                *.*                               
udp4    1251      0  *.23141                *.*
```

^^this is how a broken UDP port looks like on the shell. If I ever want to use that port number again, I seem to have to restart my machine :-(

And no, I don't have old processes hanging around that block the port. I checked with `ps aux` and with `lsof -i | grep UDP`.

**SCENARIO 2:**

- MyMacBook: start process A
- MyMacBook: open UDP port 23143 => SUCCESS
- MyMacBook: kill process A
- MyMacBook: start process A
- MyMacBook: open UDP port 23143 => SUCCESS
- MyMacBook: kill process A
- MyMacBook: start process A
- MyMacBook: open UDP port 23143 => SUCCESS
- MyMacBook: kill process A
- ...

If the port is never used, the system doesn't care if I dont close it nicely. This is how it should be.

**My question:**

What is wrong here? Of course, in a perfect world, a program wouldn't crash, and sockets are all closed with the POSIX `close` function. In an imperfect world, I just type Cmd-. in XCode to kill the app I am developing, and `close` isn't called.

When I am trying to bind my socket to an UDP port, what I am really trying to say to the OS is this: "Please OSX 10.8.5, bind my socket to port 23141. If some other program has it opened currently and is listening, then you may tell me that the port is in use, but if no running program cares about this port, then let me bind it to port 23141!!" Is this an OSX bug? Is it new? Is it a documented known bug, or a so-called "feature"?

Comment: What does `lsof -i :23141` say? It should show the process that's using the port.

Comment: My guess is that in Scenario 1 you're spawning a background process that's inheriting the socket, and it doesn't get killed when you kill process A.

Comment: No output, exit code 1. And `lsof -i | grep UDP` doesn't list my port number and not the program that opened it. `netstat -n | grep 23141` shows `udp4    1563      0  *.23141                *.* ` though, which seems pretty silly to me. `ps aux` doesn't list my app.

Comment: @Barmar: I don't spawn any processes, I don't call `fork`. I use dispatch_queues though. But I'm sure they get killed when I hit Cmd-. in XCode.

Comment: BTW... It's an UDP server that I just started developing. The data that is received doesn't produce any actions on the server app whatsoever.

Comment: Did you run lsof with `sudo`?

Comment: ok, I tried it with root: still the same result. neither the program nor the port shows up.

Comment: Looks like this has been seen before: http://superuser.com/questions/504750/kill-udp-port-that-has-no-process There's no solution there, either

Comment: He also asked here and got now answer: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71300/how-can-i-unbind-a-udp-port-that-has-no-entry-in-lsof

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in OSX.

Related posts:
https://superuser.com/questions/504750/kill-udp-port-that-has-no-process
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71300/how-can-i-unbind-a-udp-port-that-has-no-entry-in-lsof
(@Barmar: thanks for finding these articles)

1) I have noted, that if a UDP port is broken (it is bound, but not bound to a particular process), then you have to restart the computer to use this port again. Logging off, and logging in again doesn't work.

2) I found out, that there is no problem if you **disable the OSX Firewall**. This means that the problem is a bug in the standard OSX firewall. However, a broken port doen't get unbroken if you disable the firewall, you still have to restart your computer to unbreak it. But: if the firewall is off, no port becomes broken.

There is something we can learn from part 2: the OSX firewall is not a simple packet filter. It seems to hack the socket commands on a kernel level.

Maybe someone wants to write a bug report and send it to Apple... (sounds like a joke, doesn't it?)